# Spring Boot Application with different application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring boot application and I've experience in spring applications with xml and java configuration.

The applications which I was working in has the code base architecture with UI, Service, and DAO.
All these components have separate context files viz. web-applicationcontext.xml or application-servlet-context.xml, service-context.xml and data-context.xml Each of these files will have separate context confiuration for that layer viz. in the data-context.xml, the database configurations will be added  and in the ui-context.xml the dispatcher serverlet and mvc compoenets will be added. Further the web context configuration will be placed in the UI Project and database-context configuration will be placed in the database maven project. During compilation, the dao project will be complied and will be included in the service project and the service project will be included in the UI project. During context loading all the context files will be in the classpath, so all the beans will be loaded.

Now I've to have similar code base and configuration for a spring boot application. Is it possible in Spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot you can define different profiles to manage different configurations.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Furthermore @ConditionalOn* annotations could help you making your configuration flexible. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html